# State machine: Use transition matrix instead of nested switch cases C++

Tags: c++, state-machine

I am having difficulties with my state machine. I use a function that returns the new state based on input parameters oldState and two input parameters.

In this function I have a lot of nested switch cases. I'd rather use a 2x2 transition matrix but have no idea how to use it. I did make a transition table from the state diagram with sates and inputs.

But how exaclty do I use the 2 dim. array `transition_table[3][4]`?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Could you perhaps elaborate and provide some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You stated you currently have something like this:

```
StateType transition (StateType old, InputType one, InputType two) {
    //... nested switch statements
    return new_state;
}
```

So, it seems what you need is a 3-dimensional array:

```
#define MAX_STATES 12
#define MAX_INPUT_VAL 2
StateType transitionTable[MAX_STATES][MAX_INPUT_VAL][MAX_INPUT_VAL] = {
    { { StateA, StateB },
      { StateC, StateD } },
    { { StateE, StateF },
      { StateG, StateH } },
    { { StateI, StateJ },
      { StateK, StateL } },
    //...
};
```

Then you would transition like this:

```
new_state = transitionTable[StateIndex(old)][one][two];
```

So, assuming that `StateIndex(StateC)` returns `2`, then:

```
old = StateC;
new_state = transitionTable[StateIndex(old)][1][0];
assert(new_state == StateK);
```

would result in `new_state` holding `StateK`.

Comment: Nice Approach, allthough a 2x2 matrix is sufficient since the two input values are combinable bools. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Given a matrix like this:

```
state1_input1 state1_input2 state1_input3
state2_input1 state2_input2 state2_input3
state3_input1 state3_input2 state3_input3
```

When you are in state n and receive input m, you look at row n, column m to find out the new state. Assuming you have 3 possible states and 4 possible inputs, all you need to do is:

```
state = transition_table[state][input]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you don't need a 2-dimentional array, 1 dimension is fine. It should be made this way:

```
void foo()
{
int States[2] = {1,2};
int currentState = 1;///initial state, let's say
int oldState;///prev. state
while(true)
{
  if(currentState == 1 && *add any other condition that you need*)
  {
      <...>do something<...>
      oldState = currentState;//saving the old state, in case you need it.
      currentState = states[currentState]; //changing the state
  }
  else if( currentState == 2 && *add any other condition that you need*)
  {
      <...>some other code<...>
  }
}
```

So you have an array of states. You then calculate the index of that array based on your input parameters (you said you use the old state and something else for it). After that you simply get the new state from the array by that index.
My explanation is a bit messy, so leave a comment if you need a clarification of some part.

Comment: If you have more options on state choosing (I'm not sure based on your question, sorry), you can do the exact same with a 2-dimensional matrix, and use different input values for the row and the column